# Can I build a site on the .htaccess ErrorDocument?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tried a solution that works fine locally, my question is can I use it in a production version or may it causes trouble or issue?

I develop an app which gives access to users datas: a user upload things, get a link to a dedicated page that can be shared.

As far as I understand the share link of the view page could be:

```
/views/ID.html
```

if the server builds 1 page per file

```
/views/ID
```

if the server builds 1 directory + 1 index.php per file

```
/view/?id=ID
```

if view/index.php is a viewer for any user file

ID is managed by a sql db. In my case the datas are external files ( json + arrayBuffers ) loaded by xhr, and I suppose the last solution is the most rational.

But I can get this kind of share link :

```
/ID
/USERNAME/ID
/whatever/ID
```

if my viewer.php is the htaccess ErrorDocument, that analyses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], checks the query in the db .. and serves the page

This solution works and its almost transparent (except the error log). The weird side is just that the 'normal' process begins with a 404 error ... Is it a solution?

Comment: For most setups that would jettison any POST payload. So, why not just FallbackResource or a RewriteRule dispatcher?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean in 'jettison POST payload' neither what you suggest. A solution could be to encode the json in the htm pagel (if that's what you mean) but I need xhr for ArrayBuffers

Comment: Can you make your guests enter your house through the window? Yes, probably. But it's easier to just open the door. You're building a hack for something that doesn't need to be hacked.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Do you think that I should settle for a $_GET solution like /view/?id=ID ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with $_GET solution but typical solutions are mod_rewrite to handle routing within Apache or FallbackResource to handle routing within PHP (which is basically what mario's comment said).

Comment: I meant that basically the view page loads data by a GET xhr (arraybuffers). Ok thanks, mod_rewrite within htaccess is probably more relavant. But what means "FallbackResource..." ? I can embed a json but not arrays if that's what it means...

Comment: [FallbackResource](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) in this context means: invoke this PHP script for any request that doesn't map to an existing file.

Comment: Ok ! I didn't know this one .. many thanks !